# Let a and b be positive integers. The value...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a and b be positive integers. The value of xyz is $55$ and $\frac{343}{55}$ when a,x,y,z,b are in Arithematic progression and Harmonic progression respectively. Find the values of a and b.

Comment: Define $AP$ and $HP$.

Comment: Arithmetic progression and Harmonic Progression I guess....

Answer (score 1):

I guess **write up isn't clear enough but still giving it a shot..**

Case 1.

If we have **X,Y,Z** in AP,
Then we can write their product as 
LET D BE THE C.D

B= A+4D......

(B-A)/4=D

SO X,Y,Z ARE

[A+(B-A)/4],[A+2(B-A)/4],[A+3(B-A)/4]

THEIE PRODUCT = 55 = (3A+B)(A+B)(A+3B)/32

Case 2.

A,X',Y',Z',B ARE IN H.P.
SO....1/A,1/X',1/Y',1/Z',1/B ARE IN A.P

Therefore applying the same logic we can say that their product is now equal to

**X'Y'Z'=32A^3B^3/(A+3B)(A+B)(3A+B)=343/55................2**

Two equations,two unknowns..

Hint

```
*multiply them .... *
```